# Using categories and tags

Tags: categories, tags

I want to create a directory.

The categories are the niches.
the sub category of each niche are the cities that have those niches in the state.

So for example in California, say we have chiropractors.
that is the category.

One from San Francisco joins and one from Redmond...

Is it best to use sub categories for the cities or tags?

If sub categories I would have to create a new city for each different niche, right?

For example if doctor offices also signed up in both cities as the chiropractor, the same sub category could not be used, right?

Each niche would have to have their own?

So would tags be better?

So someone comes and says they need a chiropractor then it asks them for their city, and it searches tags for city, it would only show those in the category of that niche with the city name in the tag right?
Not all with the tag regardless of main category?

Comment: It sounds to me that the best solution would be to use a separate taxonomy for the location (cities). Each post can then be connected to a category as well as a city separately. On the front-end you can then create overviews of combinations of a category and a city.